# SQL - Leer un archivo txt y separar filas por espacios en blanco

Tags: sql, sql-server, text

Hola amigos estoy tratando de procesar unos txt's que recibo por parte de un sistema ajeno al mío, necesito tomar esta información y almacenarla en una tabla dentro de mi **SQL Server**, la cuestión es que mis datos viene separados por 2 caracteres, espacios en blanco muy largos y ceros. Entonces quisiera separar cada fila dentro del archivo por espacios y después si quitarle algunos ceros.
La información que recibo se va algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo qué más me interesa saber es, como separar por espacios tan largos y almacenar estas divisiones en variables todo desde **SQL**, he encontrado un poco de un tal función **BULK INSERT**.
Hasta ahora solo logrado separar una parte de cada row, y necesito todas las secciones en distintas columnas.
Este es es mi query hasta el momento

```js
   
truncate table testtxt


bulk insert testtxt
from 'C:\Users\erpre\OneDrive\Escritorio\desk2\filetxt.txt'
with(
  fieldterminator = ' ', rowterminator = '0x0a'
)

select * from testtxt
```

El problema es que los espios tiene distintas unidades, algunos son de un espacio, de 2 tabs etc .. Alguien sabe si puedo usar varios **fieldterminator** ??
Gracias a todos por su tiempo.

Comment: Solo para confirmar, ¿está seguro que la información no está separada por tabulaciones?, ¿has intentado usar el exportar directamente los resultados usando la función de `importar datos`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave pues si Mau efectivamente parece que espacios podrían ser tabs , muy listo , jamás se me abría ocurrido. Por otro lado no puedo importar directamente a SQL Server, necesito forzosamente almacenar ela rchivo y procesarlo, ya lo tengo almacenado, pero me falta meterlo a la bd.

Comment: E.Rawrdríguez, por favor [edit] su pregunta explicando cómo necesita subir este archivo txt; es decir, ¿lo hará a través de una aplicación o directamente en SQL Server?